# How to access the custom class in python?

Tags: python, kivy

I am newbies to programming, just picking up python.  I have a very simple program which is showing a popup message, and it seems OK:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class t6App(App):
    def build(self):
        lb = Label(text="Welcome Here",size_hint=(1,0.8),pos_hint={'left':1,'top':1})
        bt = Button(text="Press Me", size_hint=(1,0.1),pos_hint={'left':1,'x':0})
        fl = FloatLayout()
        fl.add_widget(lb)
        fl.add_widget(bt)
        cp = Popup(title='Guys', content=fl)
        return cp

t6App().run()
```

Then I wanted to modify it, and add more things to it, the popup didn't show then: (2 programs always the same)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class CustPop(Popup):
    def build(self):
        lb = Label(text="Welcome Here",size_hint=(1,0.8),pos_hint={'left':1,'top':1})
        bt = Button(text="Press Me", size_hint=(1,0.1),pos_hint={'left':1,'x':0})
        fl = FloatLayout()
        fl.add_widget(lb)
        fl.add_widget(bt)
        cp = Popup(title='Guys', content=fl)
        return cp

class t6App(App):
    def build(self):
        cp1 = CustPop()
        return cp1
        
t6App().run()
```

The codes do run, but it seems like the layout /button /label in CustPop() can't be accessed (became a blank popup).   My question is why and how to make it work?

Thx guys.  I am appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a `build()` method in your `CustPop`, but unlike the `App` class, that `build()` method is not automatically called. You should put that code (with a couple minor changes) in the `__init__()` method.

```
class CustPop(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustPop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        lb = Label(text="Welcome Here", size_hint=(1, 0.8), pos_hint={'left': 1, 'top': 1})
        bt = Button(text="Press Me", size_hint=(1, 0.1), pos_hint={'left': 1, 'x': 0})
        fl = FloatLayout()
        fl.add_widget(lb)
        fl.add_widget(bt)
        # cp = Popup(title='Guys', content=fl)
        self.title = 'Guys'
        self.content = fl
```

Comment: Thx you sir.   It works.   I am thinking, maybe I have been thinking in the wrong way to program in Python.   I should think of methods first instead of properties.